# How to include Authorization header in cURL POST HTTP Request in PHP?

Tags: php, http, curl, oauth

I'm trying to access mails of a user through Gmails OAuth 2.0, and I'm figuring this out through Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground

Here, they've specified I need to send this as a HTTP REQUEST:

```
POST /mail/feed/atom/ HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.google.com
Content-length: 0
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: OAuth SomeHugeOAuthaccess_tokenThatIReceivedAsAString
```

I've tried writing a code to send this REQUEST like this:

```
$crl = curl_init();
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0 
Content-type: application/json';

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST,       true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($accesstoken));

$rest = curl_exec($crl);

print_r($rest);
```

Not working, please help. :)

**UPDATE:** I took *Jason McCreary*'s advice and now my code looks like this:

```
$crl = curl_init();

$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: OAuth '.$accesstoken;

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST,true);
$rest = curl_exec($crl);

curl_close($crl);

print_r($rest);
```

But I'm not getting any output out of this. I think cURL is silently failing somewhere. Please do help. :)

**UPDATE 2:** *NomikOS*'s trick did it for me. :) :) :) Thank you!!

Comment: Shameless self promotion. You may be interested in the oAuth lib I've written: https://github.com/PeeHaa/PHPoAuthLib

Comment: Oh hey, this looks pretty cool. Will check it out later :)

Comment: @peehaa +1..... good thing must be promoted, not matter how.

Comment: @PeeHaa OK, I'm sorry.  I'll retract my statements.

Comment: you have an error in the variable name of the header, headr insted of header !

Answer (score 29, accepted):

@jason-mccreary is totally right. Besides I recommend you this code to get more info in case of malfunction:

```
$rest = curl_exec($crl);

if ($rest === false)
{
    // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
    print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
}

curl_close($crl);
print_r($rest);
```

EDIT 1

To debug you can set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true to check HTTP response with [firebug::net](https://getfirebug.com/network) or similar.

```
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

EDIT 2

About `Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK` try adding this headers (just to debug, in a production enviroment you should keep these options in `true`):

```
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for adding this.

Now I get an error saying:

Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Answer (score 53):

You have most of the code…

`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` for [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) takes an array with each header as an element. You have one element with multiple headers.

You also need to add the *Authorization* header to your `$header` array.

```
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Authorization: OAuth SomeHugeOAuthaccess_tokenThatIReceivedAsAString';
```

Comment: Hey, Um. Still not getting any output. :(

Comment: You could have more than 1 problem. Tough to tell. Any errors? You've confirmed the auth token? etc.

Comment: Yeah I'm echoing auth_token and It seems to give me a pretty long and good string. - Do check my updated code and check If anything needs be done. Thank you sooo much for your patience. :)

Answer (score -1):

use "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "application/json"