# I can't add contact to Gmail using PHP

Tags: php, google-oauth

When I try to add contact to gmail it always return 40:

> That's an error. There was an error in your request. That's all we know.

How can I solve this problem?

I tried following code

```
    $sClientId = 'ClientID';
    $sClientSecret = 'ClientSecret';
    $sCallback = 'http://humaclab.com/development/contacts/index.php/home'; // callback url, don't forget to change it to your!
    $iMaxResults = 500; // max results
    $sStep = 'auth'; // current step
    $argarray = array();

    // include GmailOath library  https://code.google.com/p/rspsms/source/browse/trunk/system/plugins/GmailContacts/GmailOath.php?r=11
    require_once "GmailOath.php";

    session_start();

    // prepare new instances of GmailOath  and GmailGetContacts
    $oAuth = new GmailOath($sClientId, $sClientSecret, $argarray, false, $sCallback);
    $oGetContacts = new GmailGetContacts();


    if ($_GET && $_GET['oauth_token']) 
    {
        $sStep = 'fetch_contacts'; // fetch contacts step

        // decode request token and secret
        $sDecodedToken = $oAuth->rfc3986_decode($_GET['oauth_token']);
        $sDecodedTokenSecret = $oAuth->rfc3986_decode($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

        // get 'oauth_verifier'
        $oAuthVerifier = $oAuth->rfc3986_decode($_GET['oauth_verifier']);

        // prepare access token, decode it, and obtain contact list
        $oAccessToken = $oGetContacts->get_access_token($oAuth, $sDecodedToken, $sDecodedTokenSecret, $oAuthVerifier, false, true, true);
        $sAccessToken = $oAuth->rfc3986_decode($oAccessToken['oauth_token']);
        $sAccessTokenSecret = $oAuth->rfc3986_decode($oAccessToken['oauth_token_secret']);

        $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token='.$sAccessToken;

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->formatOutput = true;

        $entry = $doc->createElement('atom:entry');
        $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
        $entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
        $doc->appendChild($entry);

        $cat = $doc->createElement('atom:category');
        $cat->setAttribute('scheme', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind');
        $cat->setAttribute('term', 'http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact');
        $entry->appendChild($cat);

        // add name element
        $name = $doc->createElement('gd:name');
        $entry->appendChild($name);
        $givenName = $doc->createElement('gd:givenName', 'First');
        $familyName = $doc->createElement('gd:familyName', 'Last');
        $fullName = $doc->createElement('gd:fullName', 'First Last');
        $name->appendChild($givenName);
        $name->appendChild($familyName);
        $name->appendChild($fullName);

        $content = $doc->createElement('atom:content', 'Notes');
        $content->setAttribute('type', 'text');
        $entry->appendChild($content);

        // add email element
        $email = $doc->createElement('gd:email');
        $entry->appendChild($email);
        $email->setAttribute('address', 'test@test.com');
        //$email->setAttribute('displayName', $_POST['fname']);
        //$email->setAttribute('primary', 'true');
        $email->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work');


        //insert Address
        $address = $doc->createElement('gd:structuredPostalAddress');
        $address->setAttribute('primary', 'true');
        $address->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work');
        $entry->appendChild($address);
        $postal = $doc->createElement('gd:postcode', '1212');
        $country = $doc->createElement('gd:country', 'BD');
        $fulladd = $doc->createElement('gd:formattedAddress', '1212, BD');
        $address->appendChild($postal);
        $address->appendChild($country);
        $address->appendChild($fulladd);

        $contact_detail = $doc->saveXML();


        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contact_detail);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $curlheader[0] = "Content-Type: application/atom+xml";
        $curlheader[2] = "Content-length:" . strlen($contact_detail);
        $curlheader[1] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlheader);

        $xmlresponse = curl_exec($curl);

        print_r($xmlresponse);
    }

    else 
    {
        // prepare access token and set it into session
        $oRequestToken = $oGetContacts->get_request_token($oAuth, false, true, true);
        $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $oRequestToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $oRequestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $login_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token='.$oAuth->rfc3986_decode($oRequestToken['oauth_token']);          
        echo '<a href="'.$login_url.'">login</a>';
    }
```

Comment: If that's your real clientId and clientSecret, you should probably delete this and re-post without those details (editing will preserve them in the question's history).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the GmailOath library - it seems odd to me that client secrets etc are being stored in a session.  My recommendation for accessing a Google API with OAuth is to use the Google provided PHP client libraries: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

The link above has a getting started example of how to authenticate - then uses that authentication to make an API call against a Google+ API. In your case, remove that line and instead save the value returned by `$client->getAccessToken()` and add an authorization header to the HTTPS request (rather than putting in the query string). The following has some discussion on how to do this: [How to include Authorization header in cURL POST HTTP Request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331224/how-to-include-authorization-header-in-curl-post-http-request-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

OR u can use google javascript client libray from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/downloads?csw=1