# PHP CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER won't send "Authorization"

Tags: php, curl

As a minimal test case, with PHP Version 5.6.31, cURL 7.54.0 :

```
<?php

$headers = array('Authorization: B', 'c : d');
$ch = curl_init("https://ipandheaders.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

That site reflects the headers sent:

```
Accept: */*
C: d
Host: ipandheaders.com
```

If I deliberately misspell it as:

```
$headers = array('Authorizationx: B', 'c : d');
```

The result is

```
Accept: */*
Authorizationx: B
C: d
Host: ipandheaders.com
```

or

```
$headers = array('Authorizatio: B', 'c : d');
```

gives

```
Accept: */*
Authorizatio: B
C: d
Host: ipandheaders.com
```

Using a more realistic header (with a fake token)

```
$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer JHG56HJGOJ8JH876F', 'c : d');
```

doesn't help.

```
Accept: */*
C: d
Host: ipandheaders.com
```

The error log shows no errors.

My approach seems to have worked here:
[How to include Authorization header in cURL POST HTTP Request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331224/how-to-include-authorization-header-in-curl-post-http-request-in-php)
But that was 5 years ago. Has something changed?

I tried POSTing

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

but get a 403 Forbidden error for some seemingly unrelated reason, so I don't know the outcome with POST.

Does PHP only allow an Authorization header in a POST? I can do what I want with Python 'request' using GET without problem.

If PHP's cURL extension is deliberately suppressing any Authorization header, I don't see that revealed at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php though a comment there by *tychay* seems to say that is so.

Comment: What is the output of `curl_error($ch)`?

Comment: @GentlemanMax There is no output from---> echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might help or not:

> Starting in 7.58.0, libcurl will specifically prevent "Authorization:" headers from being sent to other hosts than the first used one, unless specifically permitted with the CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH option.

Source: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html

According to the above, you might need to include the CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
```