# Store oauth access token in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0

I am working on medical web application in php codeigniter and javascript. Autheticating user by oauth password credentials. I am getting access token properly. But i dont know how to store access token in codeigniter? I tried in cookies but it not working properly.

What are the best practies to store,use tokens? I understand tokens from client, but i dont know what i should do with php coeigniter.

Thanks.

Comment: Your users should be stored in a database. If this is the case, store the tokens there

Comment: @BinarWeb i am storing users and tokens also..bt how can i pass that token to http headers

Comment: Now I understand what you've been asking. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12331224/9618184)