# browser sent an invalid request to server

Tags: php

I need to call webservice api url & fetch result....

**JSON payload** provided by API team :

```
{
"request_id": "R09",
"client_name": "CLIENT",
"services": [
{
"service_code": "REGULAR",
"service_details": [
{
"service_leg": "FORWARD",
"service_data": {
"vendor_name":"Ekart",
"amount_to_collect": 1000,
"dispatch_date": "",
"customer_promise_date": "",
"delivery_type": "SMALL",
"source": {
"address": {
"first_name": "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1": "3/1675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2": "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode": "400066",
"city": "Villupuram",
"state": "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number": "88888888"
}
},
"destination": {
"address": {
"first_name": "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1": "3/1675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2": "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode": "400066",
"city": "Villupuram",
"state": "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number": "88888888"
}
},
"return_location": {
"address": {
"first_name": "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1": "3/1675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2": "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode": "400066",
"city": "Villupuram",
"state": "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number": "88888888"
}
}
},
"shipment": {
"client_reference_id": "ABCD",
"tracking_id": "CLTC0000000001",
"shipment_value": 2000,
"shipment_dimensions": {
"length": {
"value": 1
},
"breadth": {
"value": 1
},
"height": {
"value": 1
},
"weight": {
"value": 1
}
},
"return_label_desc_1": "",
"return_label_desc_2": "",
"shipment_items": [
{
"product_id": "134883075",
"item_content":{},
"category": "Apparel",
"product_title": "Mast&HarbourBlackHandbag: Handbags",
"quantity": 1,
"cost": {
"total_sale_value": 500,
"total_tax_value": 100 ,
“tax_breakup”:{
“cgst”:0.0,
“sgst”:0.0,
“igst”:0.0
}
},
"seller_details": {
"seller_reg_name": "Seller Registered Legal Name",
"vat_id": "",
"cst_id": "",
“tin_id”:””,
“gstin_id”:””
},
“hsn” :””,
“ern”:””,
“discount”:0.0,
"legal_entity": "",
"billable_entity": "",
"cod_remittance_entity": "",
"item_attributes": [
{
"name": "order_id",
"value": "ABCD"
},
{
"name": "invoice_id",
"value": "INV1234"
},
{
"name": "item_dimensions",
"value": "l:b:h:w"
},
{
"name": "brand_name",
"value": "Peter England"
}
],
"handling_attributes": [
{
"name": "isFragile",
"value": "false"
},
{
"name": "isDangerous",
"value": "false"
}
]
}
]
}
}
]
}
]
}
```

I am calling JSon as array & passing url :

```
<?php

$url = "https://staging.logistics.com/v2/shipments/create";

$data = array
( 
"request_id"=> "R09",
"client_name"=> "DOC",
"services"=> [
array (
"service_code"=> "REGULAR",
"service_details"=> [
array (
"service_leg"=> "FORWARD",
"service_data"=> array (
"vendor_name"=>"Ekart",
"amount_to_collect"=> 1000,
"dispatch_date"=> "",
"customer_promise_date"=> "",
"delivery_type"=> "SMALL",
"source"=> array (
"address"=> array (
"first_name"=> "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1"=> "31675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode"=> "400066",
"city"=> "Villupuram",
"state"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number"=> "88888888"
)
),
"destination"=> array (
"address"=> array (
"first_name"=> "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1"=> "31675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode"=> "400066",
"city"=> "Villupuram",
"state"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number"=> "88888888"
)
),
"return_location"=> array (
"address"=> array (
"first_name"=> "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1"=> "31675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode"=> "400066",
"city"=> "Villupuram",
"state"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number"=> "88888888"
)
)
),
"shipment"=> array (
"client_reference_id"=> "ABCD",
"tracking_id"=> "DOCC0000000001",
"shipment_value"=> 2000,
"shipment_dimensions"=> array (
"length"=> array (
"value"=> 1
),
"breadth"=> array (
"value"=> 1
),
"height"=> array (
"value"=> 1
),
"weight"=> array (
"value"=> 1
)
),
"return_label_desc_1"=> "",
"return_label_desc_2"=> "",
"shipment_items"=> [
array (
"product_id"=> "134883075",
"item_content"=>array (),
"category"=> "Apparel",
"product_title"=> "Mast&HarbourBlackHandbag=> Handbags",
"quantity"=> 1,
"cost"=> array (
"total_sale_value"=> 500,
"total_tax_value"=> 100 ,
"tax_breakup"=>array (
"cgst"=>0.0,
"sgst"=>0.0,
"igst"=>0.0
)
),
"seller_details"=> array (
"seller_reg_name"=> "Seller Registered Legal Name",
"vat_id"=> "",
"cst_id"=> "",
"tin_id"=>"",
"gstin_id"=>""
),
"hsn" =>"",
"ern"=>"",
"discount"=>0.0,
"legal_entity"=> "",
"billable_entity"=> "",
"cod_remittance_entity"=> "",
"item_attributes"=> [
array (
"name"=> "order_id",
"value"=> "ABCD"
),
array (
"name"=> "invoice_id",
"value"=> "INV1234"
),
array (
"name"=> "item_dimensions",
"value"=> "l=>b=>h=>w"
),
array (
"name"=> "brand_name",
"value"=> "Peter England"
)
],
"handling_attributes"=> [
array (
"name"=> "isFragile",
"value"=> "false"
),
array (
"name"=> "isDangerous",
"value"=> "false"
)
]
)
]
)
)
]
)
]
);
echo $data=json_encode($data);
$data_string = json_encode(array(
    "Payload" => $data
));

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type : application/json"
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "Authorization : Basic ZGFpbHlvcmRlcnM6ZHVtbf4fsww="
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_close($ch);

echo "$result";

?>
```

**Response** :

```
400 Bad request
Your browser sent an invalid request.
```

Am i sending in proper format ?

Here is APi Document : https://drive.google.com/open?id=13AstBwus-uErvElg2-FN0knIy1m9lMHa

Please let me know if you need any other information....

I am using ekart api.....

Thanks in Advance....

**Update**

Below is POSTMAN result :

[image]

Update 2 :

**Error** :

{"response":[{"status":"REQUEST_REJECTED","message":["X_Merchant_Code is null "]}],"request_id":"2aa4cf98-0b59-4e2d-ba10-79c39663d6b6"}

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL & ~MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);

$url = "https://staging.ekartlogistics.com/v2/shipments/create";

$data1 = array
( 
"request_id"=> "835",
"client_name"=> "DOC",
"services"=> [
array (
"service_code"=> "REGULAR",
"service_details"=> [
array (
"service_leg"=> "FORWARD",
"service_data"=> array (
"vendor_name"=>"Ekart",
"amount_to_collect"=> 1000,
"dispatch_date"=> "",
"customer_promise_date"=> "",
"delivery_type"=> "SMALL",
"source"=> array (
"address"=> array (
"first_name"=> "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1"=> "31675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode"=> "560034",
"city"=> "Villupuram",
"state"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number"=> "88888888"
)
),
"destination"=> array (
"address"=> array (
"first_name"=> "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1"=> "31675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode"=> "110037",
"city"=> "Villupuram",
"state"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number"=> "88888888"
)
),
"return_location"=> array (
"address"=> array (
"first_name"=> "AVThamizhmahan",
"address_line1"=> "31675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
"address_line2"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"pincode"=> "110037",
"city"=> "Villupuram",
"state"=> "Tamil Nadu",
"primary_contact_number"=> "88888888"
)
)
),
"shipment"=> array (
"client_reference_id"=> "ABCD",
"tracking_id"=> "DOCC0000000001",
"shipment_value"=> 2000,
"shipment_dimensions"=> array (
"length"=> array (
"value"=> 1
),
"breadth"=> array (
"value"=> 1
),
"height"=> array (
"value"=> 1
),
"weight"=> array (
"value"=> 1
)
),
"return_label_desc_1"=> "",
"return_label_desc_2"=> "",
"shipment_items"=> [
array (
"product_id"=> "134883075",
"item_content"=>array (),
"category"=> "Apparel",
"product_title"=> "Mast&HarbourBlackHandbag=> Handbags",
"quantity"=> 1,
"cost"=> array (
"total_sale_value"=> 500,
"total_tax_value"=> 100 ,
"tax_breakup"=>array (
"cgst"=>0.0,
"sgst"=>0.0,
"igst"=>0.0
)
),
"seller_details"=> array (
"seller_reg_name"=> "Seller Registered Legal Name",
"vat_id"=> "",
"cst_id"=> "",
"tin_id"=>"",
"gstin_id"=>""
),
"hsn" =>"",
"ern"=>"",
"discount"=>0.0,
"legal_entity"=> "",
"billable_entity"=> "",
"cod_remittance_entity"=> "",
"item_attributes"=> [
array (
"name"=> "order_id",
"value"=> "ABCD"
),
array (
"name"=> "invoice_id",
"value"=> "INV1234"
),
array (
"name"=> "item_dimensions",
"value"=> "l=>b=>h=>w"
),
array (
"name"=> "brand_name",
"value"=> "Peter England"
)
],
"handling_attributes"=> [
array (
"name"=> "isFragile",
"value"=> "false"
),
array (
"name"=> "isDangerous",
"value"=> "false"
)
]
)
]
)
)
]
)
]
);
echo $data=json_encode(array("payload"=>$data1));
echo "<br/><br/>";//die;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/json", "X_Merchant_Code: DOC"));


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dailyorders:dummyKey"); //Your credentials goes here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //IMP if the url has https and you don't want to verify source certificate

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

print_r($curl_response);die;


?>
```

Comment: how are you sending the json? posting it in POSTMAN, using an ajax request, something else? How are you reading the posted JSON in your PHP script?

Comment: @chiliNUT Thanks for reply, i am using curl for this....

Comment: @chiliNUT if i calling in wrong way, please guide me how  to call in proper way to get correct response.....

Comment: are you missing method PUT on ur CURL

Comment: @YuukkaLimson i am using `post`, do i still need PUT ?

Comment: @chiliNUT do i need to pass in `json format` in php instead of `array` ?

Comment: @YuukkaLimson do i need to pass in `json format` in php instead of `array` ?

Comment: $result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  you interchanged these two

Comment: @YuukkaLimson `interchanged` still same result....

Comment: try checking your parameters again. you are nesting your json data to PayLoad which the document doesn't require. try only curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182562/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-yuukka-limson).

Comment: Ah, I see now. I think the problem is `data_string`, try it without that, so: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));`

Comment: also I dont think you need to set any other opts after you `curl_exec`

Comment: @YuukkaLimson tried as you said, still getting same result....

Comment: @chiliNUT updated as you said, still getting same result....

Comment: @YuukkaLimson here is updated code , please check : https://pastebin.com/HCBp7FTU

Comment: @chiliNUT here is updated code , please check : https://pastebin.com/HCBp7FTU

Comment: @vickeycolors try using postman if your parameters are correct. also your seeing this option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331224/how-to-include-authorization-header-in-curl-post-http-request-in-php

Comment: @YuukkaLimson i did't used postman until now, i will try now with google help.....

Comment: @YuukkaLimson when i added this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);` , i got this : `HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: close Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: Are you sure the data is supposed to be JSON-encoded _twice_, as you are currently doing with the code shown above ...?

Comment: And where in the documentation you referred to does it even say that the whole thing should be passed as one single parameter named `Payload`?

Comment: @misorude please check `update 2` part in question.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the headers you have a space between the header name and the separating colon. That results in Curl using two headers, a `Content-Type : application/json` header and a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, which is the default when posting data. The server could identify the content type as "x-www-form-urlencoded" using the second header, however the first header would cause a 400 response, because there should be no space between the header and the colon. From [rfc7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4), section 3.2.4:

> No whitespace is allowed between the header field-name and colon.  In
> the past, differences in the handling of such whitespace have led to
> security vulnerabilities in request routing and response handling.  A
> server MUST reject any received request message that contains
> whitespace between a header field-name and colon with a response code
> of 400 (Bad Request).

<!- -!>

Your code should return successful response using the headers below.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "Authorization: Basic ZGFpbHlvcmRlcnM6ZHVtbf4fsww=", 
     "Content-Type: application/json"
));
```

When debugging such issues, it's best to enable the verbose mode which prints helpful information about the connection.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

---

In your Postman request you're submitting a `HTTP_X_MERCHANT_CODE` header; you should include that in your Curl request.

```
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Basic ZGFpbHlvcmRlcnM6ZHVtbXlLZXk=",
    "Content-Type: application/json", 
    "HTTP_X_MERCHANT_CODE: DOC",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

This would fix the "X_Merchant_Code is null" error, but the server would return a new error message: "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY", pointing at: `...shipment.shipment_items[0].item_content`, because the json data does not have the required format. The `item_content` key is an empty array, which gets encoded as `[]`, but the server expects a json object (`{}`). We can fix this issue if we use a null object.

```
$data['services'][0]['service_details'][0]['shipment']['shipment_items'][0]['item_content'] = (object)null;
```

---

The complete code:

```
<?php

$data = [
    "request_id" => "835",
    "client_name" => "DOC",
    "services" => [
        [
            "service_code" => "REGULAR",
            "service_details" => [
                [
                    "service_leg" => "FORWARD",
                    "service_data" => [
                        "vendor_name" => "Ekart",
                        "amount_to_collect" => 1000,
                        "dispatch_date" => "",
                        "customer_promise_date" => "",
                        "delivery_type" => "SMALL",
                        "source" => [
                            "address" => [
                                "first_name" => "AVThamizhmahan",
                                "address_line1" => "3/1675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
                                "address_line2" => "Tamil Nadu",
                                "pincode" => "400066",
                                "city" => "Villupuram",
                                "state" => "Tamil Nadu",
                                "primary_contact_number" => "88888888"
                            ]
                        ],
                        "destination" => [
                            "address" => [
                                "first_name" => "AVThamizhmahan",
                                "address_line1" => "3/1675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
                                "address_line2" => "Tamil Nadu",
                                "pincode" => "400066",
                                "city" => "Villupuram",
                                "state" => "Tamil Nadu",
                                "primary_contact_number" => "88888888"
                            ]
                        ],
                        "return_location" => [
                            "address" => [
                                "first_name" => "AVThamizhmahan",
                                "address_line1" => "3/1675 ES Garden Vazhudaretty Post Villupuram",
                                "address_line2" => "Tamil Nadu",
                                "pincode" => "400066",
                                "city" => "Villupuram",
                                "state" => "Tamil Nadu",
                                "primary_contact_number" => "88888888"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "shipment" => [
                        "client_reference_id" => "ABCD",
                        "tracking_id" => "DOCC0000000001",
                        "shipment_value" => 2000,
                        "shipment_dimensions" => [
                            "length" => [
                                "value" => 1
                            ],
                            "breadth" => [
                                "value" => 1
                            ],
                            "height" => [
                                "value" => 1
                            ],
                            "weight" => [
                                "value" => 1
                            ]
                        ],
                        "return_label_desc_1" => "",
                        "return_label_desc_2" => "",
                        "shipment_items" => [
                            [
                                "product_id" => "134883075",
                                "item_content" => (object)null,
                                "category" => "Apparel",
                                "product_title" => "Mast&HarbourBlackHandbag => Handbags",
                                "quantity" => 1,
                                "cost" => [
                                    "total_sale_value" => 500,
                                    "total_tax_value" => 100
                                ],
                                "seller_details" => [
                                    "seller_reg_name" => "Seller Registered Legal Name",
                                    "vat_id" => "",
                                    "cst_id" => ""
                                ],
                                "legal_entity" => "",
                                "billable_entity" => "",
                                "cod_remittance_entity" => "",
                                "item_attributes" => [
                                    [
                                        "name" => "order_id",
                                        "value" => "ABCD"
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "name" => "invoice_id",
                                        "value" => "INV1234"
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "name" => "item_dimensions",
                                        "value" => "l:b:h:w"
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "name" => "brand_name",
                                        "value" => "Peter England"
                                    ]
                                ],
                                "handling_attributes" => [
                                    [
                                        "name" => "isFragile",
                                        "value" => "false"
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "name" => "isDangerous",
                                        "value" => "false"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$url = "https://staging.ekartlogistics.com/v2/shipments/create";
$data = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json", 
    "HTTP_X_MERCHANT_CODE: DOC",
);

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dailyorders:dummyKey"); //Your credentials goes here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //IMP if the url has https and you don't want to verify source certificate
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response ."\n";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks , yes its displayed 401, so i decoded and got username & password , i replaced above code by `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "dailyorders:dummyKey");` , now i am getting `{"response":[{"status":"REQUEST_REJECTED","message":["X_Merchant_Code is null "]}],"request_id":"b03e36cd-a9d8-4ac8-bb6d-0cc3b211a13d"}` , but i am passing `Merchant code` in parameter...... here is [link](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/ecom1/ekart.php)

Comment: I can't help much with that as I don't have the crdentials.

Comment: I posted php code with staging credentials  in question..... please  try from localhost or in your server only......

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try, if you trust me, but please make sure to change your credentials as soon as possible.

Comment: I think I've managed to get a successful response, I'll update my answer tomorrow :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks for your support, i also found solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Passing Merchant key in proper form solved the issue....

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://staging.ekartlogistics.com/v2/shipments/create",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"request_id\": 835,\n  \"client_name\": \"DOC\",\n  \"services\": [\n    {\n      \"service_code\": \"REGULAR\",\n      \"service_details\": [\n        {\n          \"service_leg\": \"FORWARD\",\n          \"service_data\": {\n            \"vendor_name\": \"Ekart\",\n            \"amount_to_collect\": \"5382.00\",\n            \"delivery_type\": \"SMALL\",\n            \"source\": {\n              \"address\": {\n                \"first_name\": \"Ebay\",\n                \"address_line1\": \"sqsq\",\n                \"address_line2\": \"gvhvh\",\n                \"pincode\": \"110037\",\n                \"city\": \"gvhbj\",\n                \"state\": \"Delhi\",\n                \"primary_contact_number\": \"9987654321\"\n              }\n            },\n            \"destination\": {\n              \"address\": {\n                \"first_name\": \"Dgwdh\",\n                \"address_line1\": \"C-238\",\n                \"address_line2\": \"Nagar, Amrut Nagar, Ghatkopar (W)\",\n                \"pincode\": \"560034\",\n                \"city\": \"Delhi\",\n                \"state\": \"South West Delhi\",\n                \"primary_contact_number\": \"9716632816\"\n              }\n            },\n            \"return_location\": {\n              \"address\": {\n                \"first_name\": \"Primasource Products and \",\n                \"address_line1\": \"No 99 4th Cross , Prithvi Layout\",\n                \"address_line2\": \"ECC Raod\",\n                \"pincode\": \"560034\",\n                \"city\": \"Bangalore\",\n                \"state\": \"Karnataka\",\n                \"primary_contact_number\": \"9987654321\"\n              }\n            }\n          },\n          \"shipment\": {\n            \"tracking_id\": \"DOCC0000000837\",\n            \"shipment_value\": 2000,\n            \"shipment_dimensions\": {\n              \"length\": {\n                \"value\": \"12\"\n              },\n              \"breadth\": {\n                \"value\": \"12\"\n              },\n              \"height\": {\n                \"value\": \"12\"\n              },\n              \"weight\": {\n                \"value\": \"1\"\n              }\n            },\n            \"return_label_desc_1\": \"\",\n            \"return_label_desc_2\": \"\",\n            \"shipment_items\": [\n              {\n                \"product_id\": \"895\",\n                \"product_title\": \"dwdwd\",\n                \"quantity\": 23,\n                \"cost\": {\n                  \"total_sale_value\": \"5382.00\",\n                  \"total_tax_value\": 5382,\n                  \"tax_breakup\": {\n                    \"cgst\": 0,\n                    \"sgst\": 0,\n                    \"igst\": 0\n                  }\n                },\n                \"seller_details\": {\n                  \"seller_reg_name\": \"Ebay\",\n                  \"vat_id\": \"\",\n                  \"cst_id\": \"\",\n                  \"tin_id\": \"\",\n                  \"gstin_id\": null\n                },\n                \"hsn\": \"123456\",\n                \"ern\": \"\",\n                \"discount\": \"0.00\",\n                \"item_attributes\": [\n                  {\n                    \"name\": \"order_id\",\n                    \"value\": 835\n                  },\n                  {\n                    \"name\": \"invoice_id\",\n                    \"value\": \"NA\"\n                  },\n                  {\n                    \"name\": \"item_dimensions\",\n                    \"value\": \":\"\n                  },\n                  {\n                    \"name\": \"brand_name\",\n                    \"value\": null\n                  }\n                ]\n              }\n            ]\n          }\n        }\n      ]\n    }\n  ]\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "HTTP_X_MERCHANT_CODE: DOC",
    "Authorization: Basic ZGFpbHlvcmRlcnM6ZHVtbXlLZXk=",
    "Postman-Token: bf0fd969-0618-432a-a222-d4a67bff6cd2",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Ahh i think the header http x merchant code solve ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your JSON array you have an error :

```
“vendor_name”:”Ekart”,
```

Is not quoted correctly :

```
"vendor_name":"Ekart",
```

Should work better.

There are a few more errors like this.
You should use [a JSON editor](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) to check your JSON array.

Comment: sorry, that was typo in question, thats not the problem, i updated question now....

Comment: OK, sorry. I also edited ^^ I'll edit this answer if I find some solution.

Comment: do i need to pass in `json format` in php instead of `array` ?

Comment: thanks for suggestion , please tell me how to use json through http request in my case, what code i need to update ?

Comment: The HTTP request here is managed by `curl`. The idea is to `json_encode()` data before sending -what you already do-, then decode it to use it in the request management function. It's easier because if you want, for example, to call the same server function through an AJAX HTTP request, you'll _have_ to use JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182565/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-jean-marc-zimmer).

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your params are correct.

try:

```
echo $data=json_encode($data);
//$data_string = json_encode(array(
//    "Payload" => $data
//));
   $username = "";
   $password = "";
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    //    "Authorization : yourtoken",
    //));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
         "Content-Type : application/json"
    ));
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);//since you are using basic auth  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $return = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182730/discussion-between-yuukka-limson-and-vickey-colors).

Comment: @vickeycolors awesome! Post your answer so that we would know.